# How do inits and tails work in Data.Sequence?

Tags: haskell, data-structures, sequence

Louis Wasserman wrote the current implementations of `inits` and `tails` in `Data.Sequence`. He indicates that they are very efficient, and indeed just looking at the code I can see that whatever they are doing, they are doing it in the clean, top-down sort of fashion that tends to lead to good performance for lazy trees. Unfortunately, I can't actually make heads or tails of just what they are doing. Can anyone give me a hand? The code is a bit long, but can be found on [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/src/Data-Sequence.html).

Comment: As I know they are implemented using finger trees. I am not expert but you can find more information in http://staff.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/FingerTree.html and http://apfelmus.nfshost.com/articles/monoid-fingertree.html

Comment: @akegalj, I am familiar with how the sequences are represented; Wasserman's code is just a bit ... magical.

Comment: Or, you could summon me here, and I'll answer when I have a minute to look over the code I wrote several years ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's me!

I think the best approach is probably to work through an example.  Let's have a go...

```
Deep (Two 1 2)                                                    (Two 7 8))
                (Deep (One (Node2 3 4))        (One (Node2 5 6))
                                         Empty
```

Here's a Sequence, somewhat simplified (e.g. omitting the Elem wrappers).

Let's do inits on this; tails is essentially symmetric.  Our recursive algorithm is going to leave out the empty init and only include nonempty things.

---

**Prefix**

So the prefix digit of inits is going to be generated with, essentially, `fmap digitToTree (initsDigit (Two 1 2))`.

```
initsDigit (Two 1 2) = Two (One 1) (Two 1 2)
fmap digitToTree (Two (One 1) (Two 1 2)) = 
    Two (Single 1) (Deep (One 1) Empty (One 2))
```

So those are the first two inits of the whole thing, and this digit is going to be the prefix digit of the result of `inits`.  (Except we're going to prepend the empty sequence after all we're done, but let's ignore that for now.)

---

**Inner tree**

Now let's take the inits of the inner tree, treated as a `FingerTree (Node a)` -- we're not going to pull apart the nodes yet, it's just a two-element `FingerTree` containing two nodes.   I'm not going to do the details of this, it's just recursing through the same algorithm, I'm just going to magically reach the result

```
Deep 
    (One (Single (Node2 3 4))) 
    Empty 
    (One (Deep (One (Node2 3 4)) Empty (One (Node2 5 6))))
  :: FingerTree (FingerTree (Node a))
```

So these are the inits of the inner tree.  How do these correspond to inits of the outer tree?  Each init of the inner tree corresponds to a tree containing

- the prefix digit of the original tree, `Two 1 2`
- all but the last `Node` of the init of the inner tree
- some prefix of the last `Node` of the init of the inner tree

So each `FingerTree (Node a)` acquired by taking an init of the inner tree will map to a `Node (FingerTree a)`, containing a `FingerTree` for each init of the last node in the `FingerTree (Node a)`.

So for example,  `Single (Node2 3 4)`, with its last node extracted,  will be decomposed to `Empty` and `Node2 3 4`, and the resulting `Node (FingerTree a)` is

```
Node2 
   (Deep (Two 1 2 {- prefix of original tree -}) 
         Empty 
         (One 3 {- first prefix of Node2 3 4 -}))
   (Deep (Two 1 2) 
         Empty 
         (Two 3 4 {- second prefix of Node2 3 4 -}))
```

And for the other prefix of the inner tree, `Deep (One (Node2 3 4)) Empty (One (Node2 5 6))`, extracting the last `Node` gives us the remainder `Single (Node2 3 4)` and the extracted node `Node2 5 6`, so the resulting `Node (FingerTree a)`:

```
Node2
   (Deep (Two 1 2 {- prefix of original tree -})
         (Single (Node2 3 4) {- init of the inner tree minus the last Node -})
         (One 5 {- first prefix of Node2 5 6 -})
   (Deep (Two 1 2 {- prefix of original tree -})
         (Single (Node2 3 4) {- init of the inner tree minus the last Node -})
         (Two 5 6 {- second prefix of Node2 5 6 -}))
```

So this is an operation that takes a `FingerTree (Node a)`, a single init of the inner tree, to a `Node (FingerTree a)`.  So, having recursively acquired the inits of the inner tree as a `FingerTree (FingerTree (Node a))`, we map this function over them to get a `FingerTree (Node (FingerTree a))`, which is exactly what we wanted; it's the inner tree of the inits of the entire thing.

---

**Suffix**

Finally, there are inits of the original tree composed of

- the original prefix
- the original inner tree
- each init of the suffix of the original tree

and these become the suffix digit of the tree of inits.  `initsDigit (Two 7 8)` returns `Two (One 7) (Two 7 8)`, and we essentially just map `\sf -> Deep pr m sf` over this, to get

```
Two 
   (Deep (Two 1 2 {- original -})
         (Deep (One (Node2 3 4)) Empty (One (Node2 5 6)) {- original -})
         (One 7 {- first init of original suffix digit -}))
   (Deep (Two 1 2 {- original -})
         (Deep (One (Node2 3 4)) Empty (One (Node2 5 6)) {- original -})
         (Two 7 8 {- second init of original suffix digit -}))
```

---

So, this isn't quite how the code is organized.  We've described a function from `FingerTree a` to `FingerTree (FingerTree a)`, but the actual implementation is essentially that plus an `fmap`, because we end up always needing to map the elements somehow -- even if it's just wrapping newtypes.  But this is basically what we're doing.

Comment: I must admit this still makes me more than a little dizzy, but I will continue to try to work through it. I appreciate you taking the time to explain.

Comment: I think I get the general gist of it now. It seems to just barely work, almost by accident. Finger trees are weird. Have you had a chance to look at my re-implementations of `<*>`, `*>`, and `zipWith` for `Data.Sequence`? I finally got `<*>` and `*>` into decent shape [today](https://github.com/haskell/containers/pull/141) although earlier versions made it into `containers-0.5.6.3`.

Comment: I haven't been keeping an eye on this for several years, but I can take a look tomorrow.