# What are the space complexities of inits and tails?

Tags: haskell, profiling, singly-linked-list, space-complexity

### TL; DR

After reading the passage about *persistence* in Okasaki's *Purely Functional Data Structures* and going over his illustrative examples about singly linked lists (which is how Haskell's lists are implemented), I was left wondering about the space complexities of `Data.List`'s `inits` and `tails`...

It seems to me that

- the space complexity of `tails` is **linear** in the length of its argument, and
- the space complexity of `inits` is **quadratic** in the length of its argument,

but a simple benchmark indicates otherwise.

### Rationale

With `tails`, the original list can be shared. Computing `tails xs` simply consists in walking along list `xs` and creating a new pointer to each element of that list; no need to recreate part of `xs` in memory.

In contrast, because each element of `inits xs` "ends in a different way", there can be no such sharing, and all the possible prefixes of `xs` must be recreated from scratch in memory.

### Benchmark

The simple benchmark below shows there isn't much of a difference in memory allocation between the two functions:

```hs
-- Main.hs

import Data.List (inits, tails)

main = do
    let intRange = [1 .. 10 ^ 4] :: [Int]
    print $ sum intRange
    print $ fInits intRange
    print $ fTails intRange

fInits :: [Int] -> Int
fInits = sum . map sum . inits

fTails :: [Int] -> Int
fTails = sum . map sum . tails
```

After compiling my `Main.hs` file with

```
ghc -prof -fprof-auto -O2 -rtsopts Main.hs
```

and running

```
./Main +RTS -p
```

the `Main.prof` file reports the following:

```
COST CENTRE MODULE  %time %alloc

fInits      Main     60.1   64.9
fTails      Main     39.9   35.0
```

The memory allocated for `fInits` and that allocated for `fTails` have the same order of magnitude... Hum...

### What is going on?

- Are my conclusions about the space complexities of `tails` (linear) and `inits` (quadratic) correct?
- If so, why does GHC allocate roughly as much memory for `fInits` and `fTails`? Does *list fusion* have something to do with this?
- Or is my benchmark flawed?

Comment: My only guess would be: The intermediate `Int`s aren't optimized away, so `fTails` also makes O(n^2) allocations for those. One would have to look at the core to check that (I don't have a ghc at hand).

Comment: You should probably force the list (`print $ sum intRange`) before running either `fInits` or `fTails`.

Comment: @delnan Thanks. I'm not use to inspecting core, yet, but I'll look into it.

Comment: @Cirdec Done. No changes.

Comment: For me inits allocates 2500 times as much memory as tails.

Comment: @AndrásKovács `(ಠ_ರ) ?` Are you using the same benchmark as me? Which version of GHC are you using? I've got GHC 7.10.1.

Comment: @Jubobs GHC 7.10.1 here, but I used `+RTS -s` instead of the profiler.

Comment: With windows GHC 7.8.3 I have `100.0%` allocation in `fInits` and `91.7%` of time spent in `fInits` (`+RTS -p`, same compiler options).

Comment: Ignore my GHC 7.8.3 results (and anyone elses). GHC [7.8.3 has a bug where inits is very slow](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9345). It was fixed in 7.8.4.

Comment: @AndrásKovács Where do you see a per-function breakdown in the output of `./Main +RTS -s`? What do you get if you use `+RTS -p`?

Comment: @Jubobs I just comment one or the other out when using `+RTS -s`. With `RTS -p` I got results similar to yours.

Comment: @AndrásKovács Thanks for clarifying. Do you have an explanation?

Comment: Nothing besides "the profiler is acting up". I looked at the Core and it's got nothing funny going on; it just calls `inits` and `tails` and sums.

Comment: @AndrásKovács Thanks. I just wanted confirmation that "something is afoot" and that I'm not completely crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation of `inits` in the Haskell Report, which is identical to or nearly identical to implementations used up to base 4.7.0.1 (GHC 7.8.3) is horribly slow. In particular, the `fmap` applications stack up recursively, so forcing successive elements of the result gets slower and slower.

```
inits [1,2,3,4] = [] : fmap (1:) (inits [2,3,4])
 = [] : fmap (1:) ([] : fmap (2:) (inits [3,4]))
 = [] : [1] : fmap (1:) (fmap (2:) ([] : fmap (3:) (inits [4])))
....
```

The simplest asymptotically optimal implementation, explored by Bertram Felgenhauer, is based on applying `take` with successively larger arguments:

```
inits xs = [] : go (1 :: Int) xs where
  go !l (_:ls) = take l xs : go (l+1) ls
  go _  []     = []
```

Felgenhauer was able to eke some extra performance out of this using a private, non-fusing version of `take`, but it was still not as fast as it could be.

The following very simple implementation is significantly faster in most cases:

```
inits = map reverse . scanl (flip (:)) []
```

In some weird corner cases (like `map head . inits`), this simple implementation is asymptotically non-optimal. I therefore wrote a version using the same technique, but based on Chris Okasaki's Banker's queues, that is both asymptotically optimal and nearly as fast. Joachim Breitner optimized it further, primarily by using a strict `scanl'` rather than the usual `scanl`, and this implementation got into GHC 7.8.4. `inits` can now produce the spine of the result in O(n) time; forcing the entire result requires O(n^2) time because none of the conses can be shared among the different initial segments. If you want really absurdly fast `inits` and `tails`, your best bet is to use `Data.Sequence`; Louis Wasserman's implementation [is magical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28906742/how-do-inits-and-tails-work-in-data-sequence). Another possibility would be to use `Data.Vector`—it presumably uses slicing for such things.

Comment: Very comprehensive answer. Thanks.